# Use Jitsi Meet installation with Firefox

Tags: firefox, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have followed the default installation guide of Jitsi, and it works fine using Chrome browser. However, if I use Firefox, the video nor audio is transmitted to the other side and they both view a black screen.
However, for meet.jit.si it works fine.
Is there a config that I missed in the installation?

The only error in firefox is:

```
[JitsiMeetJS.js] <getGlobalOnErrorHandler>:  UnhandledError: null Script: null Line: null Column: null StackTrace:  DOMException: AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource: Connecting AudioNodes from AudioContexts with different sample-rate is currently not supported. Logger.js:154:22
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource: Connecting AudioNodes from AudioContexts with different sample-rate is currently not supported. lib-jitsi-meet.min.js:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in my case was JVB service couldn't start.
Diagnosis:

- Only two-party chat works on Chrome
- Multiple parties chat doesn't work even on Chrome
- On Firefox doesn't work even for two parties

In the log of JVB ( /var/log/jitsi/jvb.log):

```
2020-11-17 17:01:55.470 SEVERE: [18] Health.doRun#300: Health check failed in 0ms:
java.lang.Exception: Failed to bind single-port
        at org.jitsi.videobridge.health.Health.doCheck(Health.java:143)
        at org.jitsi.videobridge.health.Health.doRun(Health.java:266)
        at org.jitsi.utils.concurrent.PeriodicRunnableWithObject.run(PeriodicRunnableWithObject.java:87)
        at org.jitsi.utils.concurrent.RecurringRunnableExecutor.run(RecurringRunnableExecutor.java:216)
        at org.jitsi.utils.concurrent.RecurringRunnableExecutor.runInThread(RecurringRunnableExecutor.java:292)
        at org.jitsi.utils.concurrent.RecurringRunnableExecutor.access$000(RecurringRunnableExecutor.java:36)
        at org.jitsi.utils.concurrent.RecurringRunnableExecutor$1.run(RecurringRunnableExecutor.java:328)
```

The problem can be resolved by either following solutions

1. stopping the service using the port 10000 (in my case it was Webmin)
2. changin the port of JVB by editting the following line in /etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties

   org.jitsi.videobridge.SINGLE_PORT_HARVESTER_PORT=10000